# Suggestion on android application development

Tags: android

I want to develop an android app for my final project, I have only 3 weeks span to develop this app, can someone please suggest me few ideas/apps which can be achieved in this time span ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't gone into detail about the skill level you have been working at.

Comment: I am just a beginner in this mobile application development thing.

Comment: My suggestion would be to try some kind of mathematics formula, for example, a primality tester. If you want something more complicated you could write a program that uses http requests or third party libraries.